# War file on Win Server Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I export my maven java project in Eclipse to War file.
On the server, I open the manager of tomact and add the war application, but when I run the application it seems the application isn't running (or some problem with the resources).
From the other hand, when I start the tomcat by the startup.bat in the tomcat folder and add the War to the webapps folder, it is working. But if I logoff the server , I cannot connect the application remotly. The server is shut down. Why?

What can be the problems?

Thanks!
Me

Comment: Could you please provide the output in the tomcat log file?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your application not running? Well - if there's a specific reason for it (and the manager application works) you will see it in the logfile - e.g. tomcat's `log/catalina.out`. Check it or give us a snippet of the error messages in there if you don't understand them.

I like to recommend not to use the manager application, rather deploy through the OS or any other maintenance tool (e.g. scripted). This typically results in a better maintainable system. As it already works well for you when you just add your WAR file to the webapps directory, everything seems well. Introducing a manager application in production just provides another means to attack your site - and I frequently see those applications poorly maintained (and the passwords poorly chosen & protected)

When you start tomcat with `startup.bat`, it will run the server process in a console window. This console process will be shut down when you log out. In order to have tomcat running even when you're not logged in (and in order for it to start automatically), you'll have to *install it as a service*. There's plenty of information on the internet on how to do this - should be extremely easy to find.